# How Do I Implement Organization Policy Constraints Via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

*Please note that this question is a Terraform question.*

When I review GCP bucket permissions, I see that Google recommends preventing public access to the objects within it via a global setting. [As described here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/org-policy-constraints), it appears that I should enable constraints/storage.publicAccessPrevention but I don't know how to do it either (a) in my project generally or (b) for a bucket specifically via Terraform.

Comment: A general-purpose answer here will not be as good as the documentation that Google has already written.

Comment: @JohnHanley -- OK, so I am thinking I somehow did not communicate. The question was "How do I do this by Terraform". I will modify the descriptive section to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running with Guillaume's response and focusing on the words "Organization Policy", I found my solution:

```
# turn off public access to storage in this project
# "Organization Policy Administrator" rights required for this to run
resource "google_project_organization_policy" "storage_public_access_prevention" {
  project = google_project.this.project_id
  constraint = "constraints/storage.publicAccessPrevention"

  boolean_policy {
    enforced = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an organisation policy, so you need to go to the organization policy page to change the value, on the project, folder or organisation (all the child resources inherited from the parent configuration)

[image]

---

Here a working terraform

```
resource "google_organization_policy" "serial_port_policy" {
  org_id     = "<ORG ID>"
  constraint = "storage.publicAccessPrevention"

  boolean_policy {
    enforced = true
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, so I am thinking I somehow did not communicate. The question was "How do I do this by Terraform". I will modify the descriptive section to make this more clear.

Comment: However your point that it's an organization policy gives me food for thought as to where in Terraform I might accomplish this -- or be unable to do so.

Comment: I missed the latest word of your question. I'm sorry! Wellspring answer sounds good

Comment: I only noticed your additional Terraform snippet after I had already posted something similar as my solution. I see we were both hitting the same example code, though, as yours is still titled "serial_port_policy", LOL... Thx again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. I tested it also and it works. happy coding :)